# Can I convert GitHub pages with Jekyll to pdf?

Tags: html, jekyll, github-pages, pandoc

I have an GitHub page that contains my [*vitae*](https://github.com/EmanuelFontelles/cv). Github renders the Jekyll page to HTML produces the website https://emanuelfontelles.github.io/cv/.

How can I convert this webpage to pdf using pandoc or even Jekyll?

Comment: Chrome/Firefox right-click anywhere on the page and "Print.." "Send to PDF"

Comment: @Meghan: I can see that on my Mac, but not in Windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#creating-a-pdf, thus for example:

```
pandoc https://emanuelfontelles.github.io/cv/ -f html-native_divs -o cv.pdf --pdf-engine=xelatex
```

The `-native_divs` is necessary to disable parsing of divs. Because pandoc looks out for the `columns` class, which is sometimes used for beamer slideshows...

Or if you don't like LaTeX:

```
wkhtmltopdf https://emanuelfontelles.github.io/cv/ cv.pdf
```

Or if you would like to use a different stylesheet:

```
pandoc -o cv.pdf --pdf-engine=wkhtmltopdf --css myprintstyles.css https://emanuelfontelles.github.io/cv/
```